# Is the repeal of Net Neutrality going to effect our ability to use apt-get?

Tags: apt, repository

I don't know if anybody has the answer to this, but it's really been bugging me, and the answers I've gotten haven't pointed to any sources.  It sounds to me like at best access to the repos would be slow, and at worst they could charge us to access them.

Are there any steps we can take to get around that, if that is the case with our particular ISP?

Comment: This discussion is ***offtopic*** and is ultimately irrelevant.  Off-topic comments and posts such as this one are not a good fit for the site.  I've purged the ongoing comments thread here, because ultimately it will end up having no useful purpose.  This is also not a general discussion forum - if you want one of those, I suggest visiting Ubuntu Forums and using their offtopic forum sections which allow for random banter (including on Net Neutrality), not here on Ask Ubuntu.  (This post is now permanently locked)